# My First Own Grover Search with Q#

Tags: q#

After I read the "[Quantum computing foundations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/paths/quantum-computing-fundamentals/)
of Microsoft I would like to be sure I understand a little the things. So, I code my own Groover search. The problem is simple. My code wants retrieve the index in array given a value. The very simple example is I have an array ["A", "B", "C", "D"] and the given value is "B" so I would like have as result 1.

I have 2 errors for the moment:

First, I have an error with my function to retrieve the index, but I think it's a  little thing.
[image]

Secondly (and most important), the output register returns me an array of bits matching with "A" and not "B" as I wish.

[image]

Someone could help me understand what I am doing wrong.

````
namespace MyFirstOwnGroversSearch {

    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;


    
    @EntryPoint()
    operation MyFirstOwnGroverSearch() : Unit {
        Message("Hello quantum world!");
        let values = ["A","B","C","D"];
        let asciiValues = [65,66,67,68];
        let asciiValuesAsBooleans = [IntAsBoolArray(65,7), IntAsBoolArray(66,7), IntAsBoolArray(67,7), IntAsBoolArray(68,7)];

        use (registerToBeMatched) = (Qubit[7]);
        // prepare registerToBeMatched -> apply an X gate to each qubit that corresponds to "true" bit in the bit string.
        let targetValue = 66; // "B";
        let targetValueAsBool = IntAsBoolArray(targetValue,7); 
        ApplyPauliFromBitString(PauliX, true, asciiValuesAsBooleans[0], registerToBeMatched);
        
        use target = Qubit();

        let markingOracle = MarkEquality(_,_,_); // put target to 1 if arrays bits are equals ( first and second args)
        let phaseOracle = ApplyMarkingOracleAsPhaseOracle(markingOracle,_,registerToBeMatched);

        // Define the parameters of the search.
        // Each character is described using 7 bits (or qubits).
        let nQubits = 7;
        // The search space is all bit strings of length nQubits.
        let searchSpaceSize = 2 ^ (nQubits);
        let nSolutions = 1;
        // The number of iterations can be computed using a formula.
        let nIterations = Round(PI() / 4.0 * Sqrt(IntAsDouble(searchSpaceSize) / IntAsDouble(nSolutions)));

        mutable answer = new Bool[nQubits];
        use (register, output) = (Qubit[nQubits], Qubit());
        mutable isCorrect = false;
        repeat {
            RunGroversSearch(register, phaseOracle, nIterations);
            let res = MultiM(register);
            // Check whether the result is correct.
            markingOracle(register, registerToBeMatched, output);
            if (MResetZ(output) == One) {
                set isCorrect = true;
                set answer = ResultArrayAsBoolArray(res);
            }
            ResetAll(register);
        } until (isCorrect);

        // Convert the answer to readable format (actual graph coloring).
        let resultAsInt = BoolArrayAsInt(answer);
        let idx = IndexOf(isEqual(resultAsInt,targetValue), asciiValues);
        //Message($"result: {BoolArrayAsInt(answer)} and index is {idx}");
    Message($"result: {BoolArrayAsInt(answer)}");
        Reset(output);
        ResetAll(registerToBeMatched);
    }

    operation isEqual (a: Int, b: Int) :  Bool {
        return (a == b);
    }
    
    operation MarkEquality(c0 : Qubit[], c1 : Qubit[], target : Qubit) : Unit is Adj+Ctl {
        within {
            for (q0, q1) in Zipped(c0, c1) {
                // Compute XOR of bits q0 and q1 in place (storing it in q1).
                CNOT(q0, q1);
            }
        } apply {
            // If all computed XORs are 0, the bit strings are equal - flip the state of the target.
            (ControlledOnInt(0, X))(c1, target);
        }
    }    

    operation ApplyMarkingOracleAsPhaseOracle(
        markingOracle : ((Qubit[], Qubit[], Qubit) => Unit is Adj), 
        c0 : Qubit[],
        c1 : Qubit[]
    ) : Unit is Adj {
        use target = Qubit();
        within {
            // Put the target qubit into the |-⟩ state.
            X(target);
            H(target);
        } apply {
            // Apply the marking oracle; since the target is in the |-⟩ state,
            // flipping the target if the register state satisfies the condition 
            // will apply a -1 relative phase to the register state.
            markingOracle(c0, c1, target);
        }
    }

    operation RunGroversSearch(register : Qubit[], phaseOracle : ((Qubit[]) => Unit is Adj), iterations : Int) : Unit {
        ApplyToEach(H, register);
        
        for _ in 1 .. iterations {
            phaseOracle(register);
            within {
                ApplyToEachA(H, register);
                ApplyToEachA(X, register);
            } apply {
                Controlled Z(Most(register), Tail(register));
            }
        }
    }

}
```
````

Comment: Sorry but the code works well. I just need to change the index here : asciiValuesAsBooleans[0]....

Comment: Do you mean that you no longer need assistance and have found what went wrong?

Comment: Yes, I found out.